# Two servers of same domain in 2 different networks?

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

I want to know if 2 servers of same domain can be in 2 different networks ?
or in other words can a dns zone file can have 2 entries of 2 servers with ip address of different networks? or can constituents of a domain be scattered in different networks ?

For ex:-

- server1.domain.com in usa with ip 192.x.x.x - my own server - also dns server running in my network
- server2.domain.com in europe with ip 185.x.x.x - my friend's server

If this is possible how reverse dns will work in this case if someone tries to find out fqdn of 185.x.x.x (my friends server in europe) when dns server is working on my network ?

Answer (score 1):

For resiliency reasons, nameservers authoritative for a given domain name **must** be in separate networks. However each nameserver should serve the exact same content for your zone or you will get into trouble (besides some very specific case of geographic load balancing or things like that, things better to left out if you are new to DNS operations).